# ZN function in Tableau

Tags: null, tableau-api

Trying to replace all the NULLs with 0% - I tried this but is saying am missing an identifier - Thank you!

ZN(LOOKUP([FY20 Q2/Q1%]), 0))

Comment: is it [FY20 Q2/Q1%] caluclated field and you have used % in the calculation ?

Comment: You have an extra closing bracket at the end.

Comment: You have a bracket to the left of ",". Remove that bracket and it should be ok